# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to deploy my NLP based spam detection model using Flask.
Below is my app.py code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import re
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words=stopwords.words('english')
```

#Lemmatization

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,render_template,escape
import pickle
import joblib

model = joblib.load('final_pickle_model.pkl')
model ='final_pickle_model.pkl'
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='template')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/prediction')
def prediction():
    return render_template('prediction.html')

@app.route('/prediction',methods=[ 'POST'])

def predict():
'''
For rendering results on HTML GUI
'''
int_features=[str(x) for x in request.form.values()]
a=int_features

msg=str(a)

filter_sentence=''

sentence=re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',msg) #cleaning

words=nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)#tokenize

words=[w for w in words if not w in stop_words]

for word in words:
    filter_sentence=filter_sentence + ' ' +str(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)).lower()


    data=(filter_sentence)

print(data)


my_prediction=model.predict(data)
my_prediction=int(my_prediction)
print(my_prediction)

if my_prediction==1:
    print("This tweet is real")
    return render_template('prediction.html',prediction_text="This tweet is real")

else:
    print("This tweet is spam")
    return render_template('prediction.html', prediction_text="This tweet is spam")

if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

If I run only my ML model, it runs perfectly without error. But when I deploy it using flask (above code), and enter the text and press predict button, I get following error:-
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'.

How to solve this error

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. It should be "Why do I have a `str` here where my code expects something with a `predict()` member?" As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, make sure you extract and provide a [mcve], including the output it produces. Your question particularly lacks a backtrace.

Comment: You can try to format your format `predict` function better, it's hard to read

Answer (score 0):

```py
model = joblib.load('final_pickle_model.pkl')
model ='final_pickle_model.pkl'
```

It seems that your `model` variable is redefined as `str`.  And this is why the error is occured, maybe you can get this `model` another name?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your problem is here:

```
model = joblib.load('final_pickle_model.pkl') <-- looks correct
model ='final_pickle_model.pkl' <-- looks out of place (probably a mistake?)
```

You have defined `model` to be a simple string and obviously a string doesn't have a `predict()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Look I dont know how to fix it excatly but I think the error is that 'str' (String module) has no pre defined function 'predict' so the function 'predict' cannot be used with a String variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to the question, and wrong on many levels. `str` is not a module. `predict` is a method of some type, not a function. Please note that we expect well informed answers that really answer the question, not guesses.